# Enable bundling for AjaxToolkit CSS

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I'm currently using the the `CompositeScript` feature of the ajax `ToolkitScriptManager` to bundle ajax .js files referenced in assemblies:

```
    <ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="manScript" LoadScriptsBeforeUI="false" EnablePartialRendering="false" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" ScriptMode="Release" EnableCdn="true">
        <CompositeScript ScriptMode="Release" Path="/web/js/ajax/ajaxbundle.min.js">
            <Scripts>
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js"  Assembly="System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"  />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="MicrosoftAjax.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="MicrosoftAjaxWebForms.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Assembly="System.Web" />
            </Scripts>
        </CompositeScript>
    </ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>
```

I'm wondering if it's also possible to bundle the generated CSS too? I'm getting an extra `<link />` which loads in CSS for the ajax `ValidatorCallout` extender control I'm using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I can see, you are using pre-v15.1 version of the AJAX Control Toolkit.
It lacks this capability.

You can upgrade your project following [Upgrading from v7.x and below](https://github.com/DevExpress/AjaxControlToolkit/wiki/Upgrading-from-v7.x-and-below) article. Take a note on [How to Use Bundling and CDN](https://github.com/DevExpress/AjaxControlToolkit/wiki/How-to-Use-Bundling-and-CDN) article during an upgrade process.